# PostgreSQL drop role with default privileges

Tags: postgresql, roles, ddl, database-permissions

I am attempting to drop a role and have severed all ties to it that I can locate, but there is one lingering issue I cannot resolve.  When I run this:

```
drop role hank
```

It tells me:

```
ERROR:  role "hank" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for default privileges on new functions belonging to role brandon in schema alteryx
privileges for default privileges on new relations belonging to role brandon in schema alteryx
```

This DDL exists on the schema:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA alteryx
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON TABLES
TO hank;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA alteryx
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO hank;
```

And when I execute the `revoke` on them, the command is successful, but the privileges remain intact.

I have scoured the DDL and can't locate how to resolve this without attempting a drop-cascade.

Any guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to run the following two statements to get rid of the default privileges that block you:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE brandon IN SCHEMA alteryx
   REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM hank;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE brandon IN SCHEMA alteryx
   REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTIONS FROM hank;
```

Comment: What is `brandon` and what is `hank` in this example?

Comment: @Gajus Those are database users (roles) mentioned in the question.

Comment: I am struggling to wrap my head around a similar scenario. In my case, I am trying to `drop role avnadmin` and I am getting an error "owner of default privileges on new functions belonging to role avnadmin in schema payments".  I am not clear what is eqv. of `hank` in my case. I tried: `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE ??? IN SCHEMA payments REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM avnadmin;`

Comment: @Gajus Use `avnadmin` instead of both `brandon` and `hank` (and use the proper schema).